# Поиск уникальных объектов в нескольких коллекциях JAVA

Tags: java

дорогие друзья. Прошу помощи.

Суть вопроса: Java, есть коллекция ArrayList с элементами Box, которые в свою очередь тоже состоят из ArrayList в которые входят объекты Rectangle. Необходимо найти набор уникальных объектов Rectangle, перебрав все элементы Box. Элементов Box может быть от 1 до 10.

Вывести результат необходимо в виде индексов уникальных элементов, например: box.get(1).get(2) - уникальный элемент

Answer (score 1):

То что вы хотите прекрасно реализуется через **stream api** буквально в одну строчку:

```
Collection<Rectangle> rectangles = boxes
                                        .stream()
                                        .flatMap(e -> e.getRectangles().stream())
                                        .distinct()
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Но чтобы метод **distinct** сработал так как надо, необходимо наличие переопределенных методов **equals** и **hashCode**